# Issue while using NS3 Topology generator

Tags: ns-3, topology

can anybody help me with the use of NS3 topology generators such as [Topology_Generator](https://github.com/idaholab/Topology_Generator).
I am getting this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The codebase is very old (3+ years), so it probably won't work with your version of NS-3 (which you didn't specified too).

I suggest you write your topology on the simulation file and verify it using the `netanim` tool.